# How to loop through a 2D array and display an index if a condition is met?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, compareto

Given,

```
Student[] students = new Student[5][7];
```

and assuming each element has been given an appropriate value, write a code segment(not a method) that will search through the array for the student whose student ID is "123456789". You should print the location(both row and column number) where the Student is stored. You can assume that the Student class contains a compareTo method. The compareTo method returns a value less than 0 if the object the method is called on has an ID number that is less that the ID number of the Student passed to the method, a value greater than 0 if the ID number of the Student the method is called on is greater than the ID number of the Student passed to the method and 0 if the ID numbers are the same.

Im not sure witch Student im actually comparing or using in the parameter of the compareTo method, or if i am even going through the loop properly. Any help is appreciated. So far i have this....

```
Employee temp = new Employee();

for(int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < employees[i].length; j++)
    {
        if(temp.compareTo(employees[i][j]) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("row " + i + "\ncol " + j);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is why you haven't made a movie in a while. Busy learning how to program I see.

Comment: @Ceelos Haha, Good one.! Still not good with programming either.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment appears to be badly written or incomplete. You are not given a way of examining a `Student`'s ID, only a method to compare two `Student` objects, so your confusion is understandable.

If there is a way to create a `Student` with a specified ID you should do so (assuming an appropriate constructor)

```
 Student goal = new Student("123456789")
```

Then use the `compareTo` method to compare the students in the arrray to the goal student, and print the values of `i` and `j` when you find it.

The reason you need to do it this way is because even though *"the Student class contains a compareTo method"* that compares the IDs, there is no way to compare a student's ID to a given ID value.  I.e. no way to ask either of the questions

> *"What is the ID of this student?"*

or

> *"Is this student's ID equal to 123456789?"*

The only questions you can ask given the assignment's current wording are

> *"Do these* two *students have the same ID?"*

and

> *"Given two students, which one has the 'smaller' (or 'greater') ID?"*.

Comment: The compareTo method actually does compare 2 Student IDs. Its just not shown. It returns 0 if the Student the method is called on has the same ID as the Student in the parameter of the method. So I since im given a 2D array of Students with size[5][7] which is already filled with Students with random IDs, I have to somehow compare each of the Students untill i find the Student with the same ID. I believe i may have to create a Student with that ID first to compare it to, but even then, im not sure if im looping the proper way and getting to every index. Thanks for the quick reply btw.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be comparing pairs of students; you should be comparing the ID of each student to `123456789`.